# UnicodeEncodeError when running in mod_wsgi even after setting LANG and LC_ALL

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8, flask

I get a `UnicodeEncodeError` error when printing a unicode string from my app. It runs via Elastic Beanstalk on AWS (Apache + mod_wsgi). I found [this](http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2014/09/setting-lang-and-lcall-when-using.html) useful, and when I call `locale.getdefaultlocale()` and `locale.getpreferredencoding()` I get `None` and `ASCII`.

I set `LANG` and `LC_ALL` to `en_US.UTF-8` (via WSGIDaemonProcess directive AND environment variables). Now when I call `locale.getdefaultlocale()` and `locale.getpreferredencoding()`, I get `('en_US', 'UTF-8')` and `UTF-8`. However, I'm still getting the same `UnicodeEncodeError`.

`sys.stdout` is of type `mod_wsgi.Log`. I couldn't find any details on how to check/set the encoding of this.

I'm not sure how to continue debugging at this point. How do I fix this error?

This wsgi.conf is the default from Elastic Beanstalk except for where I added `lang` and `locale` to the WSGIDaemonProcess directive.

```
LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so
WSGIPythonHome /opt/python/run/baselinenv
WSGISocketPrefix run/wsgi
WSGIRestrictEmbedded On

<VirtualHost *:80>
    Alias /static/ /opt/python/current/app/static/

    <Directory /opt/python/current/app/static/>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    WSGIScriptAlias / /opt/python/current/app/application.py

    <Directory /opt/python/current/app/>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    WSGIDaemonProcess wsgi processes=1 threads=15 lang='en_US.UTF-8' locale='en_US.UTF-8' display-name=%{GROUP} python-path=/opt/python/current/app:/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages user=wsgi group=wsgi home=/opt/python/current/app
    WSGIProcessGroup wsgi
</VirtualHost>
```

Traceback:

```
ERROR:discotech:Exception on /venues [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1477, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_cors/extension.py", line 110, in wrapped_function
    return cors_after_request(app.make_response(f(*args, **kwargs)))
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1461, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/opt/python/current/app/discotech/api/venue.py", line 32, in get_venues
    print "TEST = %s", test
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\\xe1' in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Here is the code I'm using to exercise it:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

...

@api_app.route('/venues')
def get_venues():
    test = u"Ián"
    print "TEST =", test
```

Comment: Couldn't you just manually call `.encode('utf-8')` on the string when printing it?

Comment: Sure, but that doesn't feel like the correct solution. I shouldn't have to worry about the output encoding when printing something. That should be handled by the environment/output stream.

Comment: Can you show how you are setting it via WSGIDaemonProcess directive and also what else you have in Apache configuration for mod_wsgi? You will have to ensure you are actually delegating the application to run in the daemon process else what you set for WSGIDaemonProcess will be meaningless. You shouldn't set the environment variables manually in your WSGI script file as not necessary and may be confusing ability to see if WSGIDaemonProcess is working okay. Do note that AWS uses old mod_wsgi version. There have been fixes related to this in more recent version of mod_wsgi.

Comment: Thanks. I edited my post with the wsgi.conf. I will try again without setting the env variables, but most of this set-up is boilerplate Elastic Beanstalk so I don't see how the app could be running outside of the daemon. Maybe I should try updating mod_wsgi?

Comment: I removed the env variable settings and the result is still the same. Note that locale.getdefaultlocale() and locale.getpreferredencoding() still report the correct UTF-8 values set in the WSGIDaemonProcess directive

Comment: FWIW. The change notes for mod_wsgi show the locale change in later versions was related to calculation for file system encoding, not default encoding for Unicode conversion. What was the full message associated with the UnicodeError you were getting?

Comment: So what is the **full** traceback of the exception? What code is triggering it? Are all components either `unicode` or `str` objects (don't mix!)?

Comment: More details added as requested

Comment: what happens if you set `PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8` envvar?

Comment: btw, `%s` does *nothing* in your code (no `%` operator) and it is not necessary (or even harmful) here. `print` converts unicode to bytes itself.

Comment: Yeah, brain fart on the print statement. Fixed it. I will try with that env var

Comment: Setting `PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8` also appears to have no effect

Comment: What was the solution?

Comment: I actually gave up :\

Comment: @jwodder's suggestion is the correct one.  In Python you should be explicitly decoding to a unicode object as data comes in and encoding to a byte string as data goes out, and specifying the encoding.

Comment: Have you put `export LANG='en_US.UTF-8'` and `export LC_ALL='en_US.UTF-8'` in `/etc/apache2/envvars`? That solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 3):

I followed advice by @kchomski and edited `/etc/apache2/envvars`:

```
## Uncomment the following line to use the system default locale instead:
. /etc/default/locale
```

The last line was commented, I uncommented it. Now my WSGI scripts are using `en_US.UTF-8` locale and everything works fine!

Comment: @Cluster I did it several times in my life before found this way to solve it. Btw, you can upvote an answer if you found it useful :)