# How to set preferred encoding in WSGI to UTF-8

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache, utf-8, mod-wsgi

Feeling a bit crazy here. I've got Apache set up with mod_wsgi, but I can't get the encoding to work properly. I have:

- tested that mod_wsgi is running in daemon mode
- read [Graham Dumpleton's blog post](http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2014/09/setting-lang-and-lcall-when-using.html) about setting up the `lang` and `locale` settings for the `WSGIDaemonProcess` directive.
- created a minimal test that seems to demonstrate the issue

```
# I recompiled the mod_wsgi file to get the Python version correct
sys.version = '3.8.6 (default, Sep 24 2020, 21:54:23) \n[GCC 8.3.0]'
sys.prefix = '/usr/local'
sys.path = ['/usr/local/lib/python38.zip', '/usr/local/lib/python3.8', '/usr/local/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages', '/usr/local/src/scorched']

# This seems to be a timing thing? Not sure, but possibly problematic
locale.getlocale() = (None, None)
# This was fixed by setting lang or locale (not sure which)
locale.getdefaultlocale() = ('en_US', 'UTF-8')
sys.getdefaultencoding() = 'utf-8'

# These seem like a problem...
sys.getfilesystemencoding() = 'ascii'
locale.getpreferredencoding(False): 'ANSI_X3.4-1968'

# It's daemon mode
mod_wsgi.process_group = 'cl'
```

My WSGI configs look like this:

```
    WSGIScriptAlias / /opt/courtlistener/docker/apache/wsgi-configs/python_version_test.py
    WSGIDaemonProcess cl \
      threads=10 \
      processes=64 \
      python-path=/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ \
      lang='en_US.UTF-8' \
      locale='en_US.UTF-8'
    WSGIProcessGroup cl
    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
    WSGIPassAuthorization On
```

When I log into the server and start `python` in the terminal, this line works fine, but **it fails when it runs via mod_wsgi**:

```
from reporters_db import REPORTERS
```

All that line does is import a json file that has some utf-8 content in it. Here's the code behind that import:

```py
db_root = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
with open(os.path.join(db_root, "data", "reporters.json")) as f:
    REPORTERS = json.load(f, object_hook=datetime_parser)
```

Since the json call above doesn't have the encoding specified, it uses ASCII and fails:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/opt/courtlistener/docker/apache/wsgi-configs/python_version_test.py", line 6, in <module>
     from reporters_db import REPORTERS
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/reporters_db/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
     REPORTERS = json.load(f, object_hook=datetime_parser)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/json/__init__.py", line 293, in load
     return loads(fp.read(),
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/encodings/ascii.py", line 26, in decode
     return codecs.ascii_decode(input, self.errors)[0]
 UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 441720: ordinal not in range(128)
```

How can I tell it (and the rest of my codebase) to use utf-8 like sane adults?

---

#### Edit 1

Perhaps it is important to mention that I'm running apache with the following command:

```
exec apache2ctl -D FOREGROUND "$@"
```

I thought that would source the `/etc/apache2/envvars` file, so I appended the following to that file:

```
export LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
```

And I tried tweaking my startup command to:

```
LANG="en_US.UTF-8" exec apache2ctl -D FOREGROUND "$@"
```

I was hopeful, but no. Still no progress.

Comment: I think you went crazy. Recompiling [which doesn't matter, `sys.path = ['/usr/local/lib/python38.zip'`, and all things. You know..., locales are not used by default. You should call `locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')` if you want to setup the locale. but I would put `encoding='utf-8` on every `open`: better to be explicit! (and you should not care about locale but for error message and logs. To/From webserver; be explicit

Comment: Turns out the `en_US.utf-8` locale wasn't installed b/c I had a slim docker image. Ugh. See my answer for details. I think explicitly setting the encoding on every file read is something that Python3 is trying to save us from doing. I'd be very sad if I had to do that.

Comment: No, Python3 is about having consistent encoding within python (BTW Unicode, not UTF-8). But the file you read from outside and you save outside Python should be explicitly marked. UTF-8 is not yet universally used (e.g. on Windows). And as you see for your problem, standard POSIX locale is C (so ASCII). In any case your job should be outside locale (because you should care about locale of webpages, not of the system). And "explicit" helps also as documentation. And you may need to use JSON file with other encodings. Really: better to be explicit.

Comment: I think you misunderstand the issue a bit. The `json.load` call is actually loading [a file](https://github.com/freelawproject/reporters-db/blob/master/reporters_db/data/reporters.json) from within the code base itself. It's not an outside file, we control it, and we know that it's unicode. I agree that when you get outside stuff you gotta handle the encodings explicitly.

Comment: Just posting a year+ later to say that I was wrong. Putting the encoding on every file open is good practice even in Python 3, and even though I think that's dumb. I don't think doing that would have quite fixed the problem here, but it would have helped!

Comment: Strongly related: [UnicodeEncodeError when running in mod_wsgi even after setting LANG and LC_ALL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30634777/95735)

Answer (score 5):

Well, I finally figured this out by searching for every time Graham Dumpleton mentioned the word "lang" on the Internet. That eventually turned up [this thread](https://groups.google.com/g/modwsgi/c/7qub8mWWDjQ?pli=1), which mentioned that it was possible to not have a locale installed. I was able to check that by running `locale -a` inside my Ubuntu Docker image, which revealed:

```
locale -a
C
C.UTF-8
POSIX
```

So that's the issue! `mod_wsgi` doesn't know what I'm asking for when I ask for `en_US.utf-8`, and it doesn't throw an error either. Swapping my settings to instead be set to `C.UTF-8` fixed this immediately.

I'm running a slim docker image, so that must be why I lack locales. I also don't have a file at `/etc/default/locale` that a lot of other answers in this general area refer to.

I've filed this as [a bug](https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/issues/625).

Comment: Five months later, I'm still annoyed about this issue and thinking about it a little. It was a big reason we spent the time last year to switch to nginx. Our performance has been through the roof since we did. If you're still using Apache and if you're landing on this answer, I think the real fix is to seriously consider switching to nginx instead of using this fix.

Comment: Another nine months later, and I am reading this and I'm still annoyed. Yikes, this one got under my skin. No more apache for me, I think, ever.

Comment: It would be me more helpful to describe how configuring a locale works in nginx (and why you think it is better than in Apache) instead of complaining about Apache.

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar UnicodeDecodeError issue when parsing a yaml file containing Unicode characters on Debian 11, Apache2, mod_wsgi.

It was enough to set WSGIDaemonProcess locale to C.UTF-8, then the error went. This single line changed in my /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

```
     WSGIDaemonProcess my_app locale='C.UTF-8'
```

In the question, mlissner mentioned a bunch of settings tried, but those were not needed for me.

Comment: Nice, thanks for the contribution! Good to see this answer helped.

Comment: You are welcome. You tried everything so I only had to pick the solution.

Comment: 12 years later and this question really saved my bacon!