# Python opening files with utf-8 file names

Tags: python, linux, file, encoding, utf-8

In my code I used something like `file = open(path +'/'+filename, 'wb')` to write the file
but in my attempt to support non-ascii filenames, I encode it as such

```
naming = path+'/'+filename
file = open(naming.encode('utf-8', 'surrogateescape'), 'wb')
write binary data...
```

so the file is named something like `directory/path/\xd8\xb9\xd8\xb1\xd8\xa8\xd9.txt`
and it works, but the issue arises when I try to get that file again by crawling into the same directory using:

```
for file in path:
    data = open(file.as_posix(), 'rb)
    ...
```

I keep getting this error `'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position..`
I tried converting the string to bytes like `data = open(bytes(file.as_posix(), encoding='utf-8'), 'rb')` but I get `'utf-8' codec can't encode characters in position...'`

I also tried `file.as_posix().encode('utf-8', 'surrogateescape')`, I found that both encode and print just fine but with open() I still get the error `'utf-8' codec can't encode characters in position...'`

How can I open a file with a utf-8 filename?

I'm using Python 3.9 on ubuntu linux

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**

I figured out why the issue happens when crawling to the directory after writing.
So, when I write the file and give it the raw string `directory/path/\xd8\xb9\xd8\xb1\xd8\xa8\xd9.txt` and encode the string to utf, it writes fine.
But when finding the file again by crawling into the directory the `str(filepath)` or `filepath.as_posix()` returns the string as `directory/path/????????.txt` so it gives me an error when I try to encode it to any codec.

Currently I'm investigating if the issue's related to my linux locale, it was set to POSIX, I changed it to C.UTF-8 but still no luck atm.

More context: this is a file system where the file is uploaded through a site, so I receive the filename string in utf-8 format

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the 2-minute [tour]. 
Moreover, open [Help] and read at least [ask]. Then, [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

Comment: `open` takes a Unicode `str` for a file name. No need to encode.

Comment: A `byte` object is not a raw string. It's important to understand the difference between `byte` and `str` objects, which is reasonably well described in the Python documentation. In summary, a `byte` object is a sequence of bytes (as its name implies). Each element in a `byte` is an *integer*, whose value is between 0 and 255. A `str` object is a sequence of characters, whose internal storage format is not exposed. Since there is no character object, an element in a `str` is another `str` of length 1. Every element of a `str` has a Unicode codepoint, an integer between 0 and 0x10FFFF.

Comment: The Python library lets you use three types of objects for filepaths: `str` objects, `byte` objects, and `Path` objects. In the end, these are mapped onto filenames in an operating-system-dependent manner; `byte` objects are the underlying bytes which the OS uses. `str`objects, at least by default on Unix-like systems, are turned into UTF-8 byte sequences. That almost always has the desired result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after being in a rabbit hole for the past few days, I figured the issue isn't with python itself but with the locale that my web framework was using. Debugging this, I saw that

```
import sys
print(sys.getfilesystemencoding())
```

returned 'ASCII', which was weird considering I had set the linux locale to C.UTF-8 but discovered that since I was running WSGI on Apache2, I had to add locale to my WSGI as such `WSGIDaemonProcess my_app locale='C.UTF-8'` in the Apache configuration file thanks to [this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72188089/19797657)

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you feel you need to recode filepaths.

Linux (unix) filenames are just sequences of bytes (with a couple of prohibited byte values). There's no need to break astral characters in surrogate pairs; the UTF-8 sequence for an astral character is perfectly acceptable in a filename. But creating surrogate pairs is likely to get you into trouble, because there's no UTF-8 encoding for a surrogate. So if you actually manage to create something that looks like the UTF-8 encoding for a surrogate codepoint, you're likely to encounter a decoding error when you attempt to turn it back into a Unicode codepoint.

Anyway, there's no need to go to all that trouble. Before running this session, I created a directory called ´ñ´ with two empty files,  and `mañana`. The first one is an astral character, U+1D510. As you can see, everything works fine, with no need for manual decoding.

```py
>>> [*Path('ñ').iterdir()]
[PosixPath('ñ/'), PosixPath('ñ/mañana')]
>>> Path.mkdir('ñ2')
>>> for path in Path('ñ').iterdir():
...   open(Path('ñ2', path.name), 'w').close()
...
>>> [*Path('ñ2').iterdir()]
[PosixPath('ñ2/'), PosixPath('ñ2/mañana')]
>>> [open(path).read() for path in Path('ñ2').iterdir()] 
['', '']
```

**Note:**

In a comment, OP says that they had previously tried:

```py
file = open('/upload/\xd8\xb9\xd8\xb1\xd8\xa8\xd9\x8a.png', 'wb')
```

and received the error

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 8-11: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Without more details, it's hard to know how to respond to that. It's possible that `open` will raise that error for a filesystem which doesn't allow non-ascii characters, but that wouldn't be normal on Linux.

However, it's worth noting that the string literal

```
'/upload/\xd8\xb9\xd8\xb1\xd8\xa8\xd9\x8a.png'
```

is not the string you think it is. `\x` escapes in a Python string are Unicode codepoints (with a maximum value of 255), not individual UTF-8 byte values. The Python string literal, `"\xd8\xb9"` contains two characters, "O with stroke" (`Ø`) and "superscript 1" (`¹`); in other words, it is exactly the same as the string literal `"\u00d8\u00b9"`.

To get the Arabic letter ain (`ع`), either just type it (if you have an Arabic keyboard setting and your source file encoding is UTF-8, which is the default), or use a Unicode escape for its codepoint U+0639: `"\u0639"`.

If for some reason you insist on using explicit UTF-8 byte encoding, you can use a `byte` literal as the argument to `open`:

```py
file = open(b'/upload/\xd8\xb9\xd8\xb1\xd8\xa8\xd9\x8a.png', 'wb')
```

But that's not recommended.

Comment: I understand but that's not the behaviour I'm seeing for some reason, using no encoding I have `file = open('/upload/\xd8\xb9\xd8\xb1\xd8\xa8\xd9\x8a.png', 'wb')` I get `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 8-11: ordinal not in range(128)` 
I read somewhere about open() that "Python's default encoding is ASCII. You can easily change it by passing the encoding parameter." but I can't use an encoding parameter when using binary mode. So I'm not sure if I'm missing something or if I'm going about this all wrong

Comment: for context the issue I'm having is with Arabic letters, so \xd8\xb9 for example is one letter ع so maybe the issue has something to do with that?

Comment: What kind of filesystem is mounted at `/upload'? I cannot reproduce the UnicodeEncodeError on my Ubuntu system.

Comment: The quote about `open()` is referring to the file's *contents*, not its name. And Python's default encoding is not Ascii. On Ubuntu, it will normally be UTF-8. That quote seems to be from an outdated version of a page on www.programiz.com (not a site I would recommend in any case); it's been corrected in the [current version](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/file-operation). But you should get into the habit of reading the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=open#open), which actually tells you what Python does.

Comment: @spospider; I updated my answer to take your comment into account. But you really need to provide more details about how you get that `UnicodeEncodeError`, preferably by editing your question.

Comment: I appreciate your help, I apologize if I'm a bit hasty in searching for information. I managed to narrow down the issue, updated the question. Thanks